# Input text color change

Tags: forms, contacts

I have contact form but one issue is not solve please any one guide me
I clicked in input field text is black
and
I unclicked this field text is white

I want both white color

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a selector in CSS called `:focus` which gets triggered when you click/focus the input area. Use this to change the input color when touched or focused.

```css
input:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

Check this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) for more reference about the focus selector.